# Block URLs that don't contain query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

Using mod_rewrite how can I block a URL that does **NOT** contain the query string on the end.

My website uses /get.php?page=blah in several different folders

I see a lot of bots/something hitting every file get.php without the query string. So I want to deny access to get.php when it is requested without ?page=whatever

I am struggling to work it out

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \^get.php$  [NC]  
RewriteRule .*  - [F]
```

Everything I search for regarding this comes up with how to turn query strings into friendly URLs, this is not what I a trying to achieve though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule (^|/)get\.php$ - [NC,F]
```

Comment: this didn't work for me I do not think it was exactly what I meant. I probably didn't explain well. I was trying to redirect get.php when it exists without a query string attached to forbidden. The query string won't always be the same either.

Comment: thanks for the update, this works much better now :) the only problem is it only is working in the directly the htaccess file is in (root). It works for /get.php but doesn't work for /folder/get.php

Comment: thank you this is just how I hoped it would be! I really appreciate the help